# In a finite dimension Hilbert space, can I always construct a unitary operator that can take me from state $a$ to state $b$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, unitarity

Say in a 2 dimensional hilbert space, I want to transform from $\left|a\right>$ to $\left|b\right>$. The operator $M = \left|b\right>\left<a\right|$ can do that. But it is not unitary. Given I know $\left|a\right>$ and $\left|b\right>$ exactly, can I always construct a particular (not universal) unitary operator $U_{ab}$ such that $U_{ab}\left|a\right> = \left|b\right>$?

Comment: Hint: $U = |b \rangle \langle a | + |a \rangle \langle b |$.

Comment: @DanielSank: that's only unitary if a and b are orthogonal, I think.

Comment: @Javier correct.

Comment: Under unitary operators inner products and norms (lengths) remain unchanged. So, you must have a priori $\:\Vert a \Vert =\Vert b \Vert \:$, otherwise it's impossible to find a unitary operator as in your question.

Comment: @Frobenius:  But the state $|a\rangle$ always has  a representative of any desired (non-zero) length, which dispenses with your concern.  (I am assuming here that kets represent states, not vectors (per the wording of the question), which I believe is standard usage, but correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: @WillO : You're absolutely right. My comment is a clarification, not a correction, in order to remind us that it's convenient to normalize the states as you have done essentially in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as long as $\langle b|b\rangle =\langle a |a\rangle$. This condition is necessary because $|b\rangle = U|a\rangle$ then $\langle b|b\rangle =\langle a|U^†U| a\rangle = \langle a | a\rangle$

We can consider the case there $\langle b|b\rangle =\langle a |a\rangle = 1$. Find two orthonormal bases $\{|a_i\rangle\}$ and $\{|b_i\rangle\}$ where $|a_1\rangle = |a\rangle$ and $|b_1\rangle = |b\rangle$. This is always possible in finite dimensions using the Gram-Schmidt procedure.

Then you can check that the operator
$U_{ab} = \sum_i |b_i\rangle \langle a_i |$
is unitary by confiming that $UU^† = U^†U = I$ and $U_{ab}|a\rangle = |b\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

Represent $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ by vectors of norm 1.  Choose your basis so $|a\rangle=\pmatrix{1\cr 0\cr}$.  Then you want a unitary matrix whose first column is $|b\rangle$.  Take the second column to be orthogonal to the first and you're done.